# sql more than one count

Tags: sql

I have a database with Names of workers, names of projects they are working on, names of tools they know how to use and name of languages they speak, among other data. I want to create an SQL query in R that gives me the name of each worker with a count of how many projects they are working on, how many tools they know how to use and how many langauge they speak. For example: Miller 5 3 2.

I have tried this code:  (it's not working)

```
sql= "SELECT Name.worker, count(Name).project, count(Name).tool, count(Name).language 
      FROM worker GROUP BY worker"
```

any ideas? :)

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Perhaps `count(distinct project) as Project_Count, count(distinct tool) as Tool_Count, count(distinct lanaguage)  as Language_count`  table structure seems odd.  I would expect at least one  join needed here to get the workers languages, tools, and projects.  I wouldn't expect it to be de-normalized to a worker table...  The cardinlity between worker and the other objects (project,tools, languags) is looks to be 1:M and thus seemingly would need joins or multiple rows for the same worker in the "worker" table...